# ¿Cómo soluciono un problema de paginación en Joomla?

Tags: joomla3

soy el nuevo administrador de este sitio http://acrip.co/ y me encuentro de que la paginación, de la seccion de noticias no funciona.

Los dueños me dicen que hace poco hicieron un cambio de DNS, ya que lo tenian con otro proveedor, pero yo no creo que este sea el problema.

Alguien sabe cual es la extención (o plugin) que administra la paginación?

GRACIAS

Comment: Por lo visto es un problema del dominio base, que está mal definido en Joomla, o en el htaccess

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ... sabes si hay alguna forma de definirlo desde joomla? o en el htaccesss?. GRACIAS